# Cant create BIDS project in VS2008

Tags: ssis

Client :
- Windows 7 SP1 32bit
- With SQL Express - Advance series installed (with VS2008)

Server:
- Database: SQL Server 2008R2 Enterprise Ed., 64bit
- OS: Windows Server 2008

I always get the message "To design IS packages in BIDS, BIDS has to be installed"
What am I missing here?

Really need your help guys, first time using VS much more the BIDS.

[image]

Thanks,
Elmer

Comment: That error message seems pretty clear to me my good man.

Comment: Hi Zane. It's odd cause I can use VS2008 after I have installed the SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU. I can even create a SSIS project but that error fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install BIDS on your client machine.  BIDS is not included as part of Visual Studio, it is part of SQL Server (but runs in the Visual Studio shell).  So get your SQL 2008R2 media and run the installation a new instance or add features.  You don't need any of the Instance Features, but you should include the following Shared Features:

- Business Intelligence Development Studio
- Client tools Connectivity
- Client tools SDK
- Management Tools - Complete
- SQL Client Connectivty SDK

Comment: Hi Mark. Correct me if I'm wrong, BIDS is part of VS2008 when I installed the SQL Server 2K8R2 express with advance series. The features I have added during the install process

Comment: Hi Mark. Got it working by using the SQL Server 2K8 R2 Enterprise installer. Thanks